# What should i use to display a streaming url on my android app?

Tags: java, android, url, live-streaming

I want to display a live-streaming on my android application (from a IP camera in this case) using the URL of the streaming.

The streaming is being shown on a webpage, so basically what I want to do is to display it from to the webpage, straight to my application.

Should I use Picasso, `WebView` or `ImageView` in this case?, which one is more efficient and why? or should I use another tool?

Thanks very much for reading, I´m kinda lost with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Picasso and ImageView can't deal with video streaming. You should use VideoView, but it is very limited for various media formats, at first try it, if it don't work, try

1. [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/Download/), easy to use, but has large delay for rtmp and rtsp streams
2. [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/), this is a good choice for rtmp and rtsp streams, but you need to find ffmpeg port for android, for example this [AndroidFFmpeg](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg), but you can find more, personally I used this [sodaplayer](https://github.com/sodapanda/sodaplayer), for rtmp streams, and it has very little delay, comparing to vitamio or web plugin.
3. [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) I used a lot, great library, a little hard to use, but when you experience with it, it can be very helpful

I used this 3 libraries, and it depends what kind of stream is it, all have their good and bad sides, depends on stream format.

Comment: i really, really need some advice, is there any way i can communicate with you ? (ant email or facebook)